# Установка Linux в D-Link

Tags: linux, маршрутизатор, d-link

Интерестно, есть ли на форуме люди, которые представляют себе, как собрать Линуксовое ядро и установитить его в маршрутизатор D-link, ну или любой другой!?

Comment: А что именно вас интересует?

Comment: Меня ещё интересует вопрос, а драйвера на железо маршрутизатора нужно ставить?:)


Comment: По поводу драйверов я не знаю. У нас были специальные железки. Чуть позже проясню ситуацию у коллег, чтоб не соврать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Задача сборки прошивки для девайса(роутер или что-то еще,- не важно) вообще говоря достаточно сложна:

Чтобы собрать прошивку надо иметь исходники ядра, rootfs и тематического софта(того, который делает железки разными: веб-интерфейсы, приложения и т.п.). Скорее всего Ваша железка не содержит процессора х86 семейства. Соответственно Вам потребуется набор кросстулов(gcc, binutils) для компиляции ядра на x86 хост-машине.

Скорее всего у Вас нет такого набора тулов от производителя железки, т.е. придется сначала собрать тулы. Уже на этом первом шаге у Вас могут возникнуть проблемы, типа: есть вероятность, что Вы не сможете найти правильный пакет gcc, который сможет генерить код на Вашу target железку.

Если Вы нашли и собрали кросстулы, следующий пункт сборка ядра, модулей ядра(если они есть) и rootfs, если ее нет готовой. Здесь проблема в том, что у Вас скорее всего нет исходников всех необходимых драйверов/модулей (хотя может для роутера найдется все - я хз).

Следующий пункт сборка приложений(если они есть), конфигурирование и укладка всего что есть в target файловую систему для сборки образа для заливки(это если у Вас прошивка единим образом кладется. Бывают случаи когда ядро и rootfs отдельно, а все остальное отдельно ставится уже после установки ядра и rootfs).

Теперь если у Вас образ для заливки на руках, то надо разбираться со способом залики образа на коробку, мне известны следующие варианты:

- поднимаем на хосте прошивочный сервер, соединяем железку с хостом езернетом - жмем кнопки на железке и включаем ей питание. После начала процеса прошивки отпускаем кнопки.
- записываем образ на USB-флеху, втыкаем в железку USB-флеху, жмем кнопки - вкл. питание.
- используем JTAG - шьем аппаратно.
- загружаем железку в bootloader(сюда заходим через сериал-терминал), в бутлоадере скачиваем прошивку через tftp, там же прошиваем.
- загружаем железку в bootloader, в бутлоадере монтируем образ ядра через nfs, загружаемся в линукс с nfs.

В процессе сборки/прошивки могут возникать следующие проблемки:

- криво собрались/прошились,- бутлоадер в наличии - пересобираемся/прошиваемся заново)
- криво прошились,- убили бутлоадер,- железка не встала - ищем JTAG)
- криво прошились,- железка не встала, сдохла флеха на железке - несем ее на свалку)

Вобщем процесс увлекательный))

Comment: Нда... Пришол к выводу что лучше собрать маршрутизатор на базе PC + RedHat, единственный минус потребляемая мощность и шум...

Comment: А чем собсно стандартная прошивка не устраивает?

Comment: Отсутствует OpenVPN...

Answer (score 1):

В точности не помню, что использовал, но общий вердикт таков. Компиляция проходит на виртуальной машине, с настроенным окружением (компилятор, линковщик, libc и т.д.). После получения образа, подключаемся к маршрутизатору (обычно настраивается соединение через ком-порт) через PuTTY. Любая "коробка" содержит загрузчики ядра, те есть скрипт для загрузки скомпилированного образа. Далее настраиваем Boot Loader на работу с вашей осью.

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не поставить на него что-нибудь уже готовое? Я, лично, предпочитаю dd-wrt. Рассматривайте это по аналогии с готовыми дистрибутивами для десктопов — уже готовый дистрибутив для роутера :). Дальше делайте с ним всё, что нужно — ssh есть, а чего ещё не хватает для счастья?

Comment: OpenVpn прийдётся ставить ручками отдельно?

Comment: OpenVpn входит в стандартную поставку dd-wrt. http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/OpenVPN

Comment: Спс!

Answer (score 0):

[dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database)
еще были статьи в Хакере и на Хабре

Comment: Вы принципиально не читаете предыдущие ответы? Сделайте по странице поиск по слову «dd-wrt» — узнаете много интересного.

Comment: не вижу ни одной ссылки

Comment: Ладно, видимо нет смысла это обсуждать дальше.

Comment: Но Вы, всё же, попробуйте волшебное клавиатурное сочетание Ctrl+F.

Comment: А вы познакомьтесь с кнопкой редактировать рядом с комментарием.